# requestFocus() works on Mac but not on Windows

Tags: java, windows, macos, swing, user-interface

In my program I have a JTabbedPane which requests focus to listen to some key events, and it works fine on my mac. However when I switch over to a Windows machine, the focus seems to be lost. Key events can't be listened to anymore.

I have `setRequestFocusEnabled(true)` as well in windows, which I didn't need on my mac.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Answer (score 1):

`requestFocus`, is discouraged because it tries to give the focus to the component's window, which is not always possible.In modern JDKs, you should stick with the `requestFocusInWindow` method

Did you try that method ?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem myself, you need to use keybindings to get it working properly. You bind the key stroke to particular action :). The inputmap is then linked to the actionmap via the String key (in my example "space").
You can either use an anonymous inner AbstractAction class, though it may throw errors if you are calling non final variables. So in that class call a new private class that extends AbstractAction

```
    JPanel component = (JPanel)frame.getContentPane();
//THIS IS THE KEY BINDING CODE
        component.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"), "space");
        component.getActionMap().put("space", (new AbstractAction(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                Timer timer = new Timer();

                timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
                public void run(){
                        grid.stepGame();
                    }
                },250, 250);



            }}));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

From the JavaDocs for [`requestFocus()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocus%28%29):

> Note that the use of this method is discouraged because its **behavior is platform dependent.** Instead we recommend the use of [`requestFocusInWindow(boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocusInWindow%28boolean%29)